# KnockoutJS: Observable not being notified

Tags: knockout.js, typescript, observable

In my ViewModel I have the following properties:

```
logisticsDestinations: KnockoutObservableArray<Destination>;
filteredlogisticsDestinations: KnockoutComputed<Destination[]>;
logisticsDestinationsFilter: KnockoutObservable<string>;
showNotAddressable: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
```

In my constructor I instantiate like this:

```
//Data from back-end, this works
self.logisticsDestinations = ko.observableArray<Destination>(lines); 
self.showNotAddressable = ko.observable<boolean>(true);
self.logisticsDestinationsFilter = ko.observable<string>("");
self.filteredlogisticsDestinations = ko.computed(() => {
    //subscribe to properties
    //self.showNotAddressable();

    var result = self.logisticsDestinations();

    if (self.logisticsDestinationsFilter().length > 0) {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.logisticsDestinations(),
            item => (item.name.peek()
                .toLocaleUpperCase()
                .indexOf(self.logisticsDestinationsFilter.peek().toLocaleUpperCase()) >=
                0));
    }

    if (!self.showNotAddressable.peek()) {
        result = ko.utils.arrayFilter(result, item => (item.isAddressable.peek()));
    }

    return result;
}).extend({ paging: '10', rateLimit: 500 });
```

Now when I fill text in `logisticsDestinationsFilter` my `filteredlogisticsDestinations` gets computed. However when I check  `showNotAddressable` it does not get computed.

I can get this to work by calling `self.showNotAddressable();` first in the computed. But that doesn't seem like a good way of working and why would it work for the filter and not the Addressable?

Any ideas, suggestions?

Thanks!
Thomas

Comment: You cause this, [explicitly](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-dependency-tracking.html), by using `peek`?

Comment: KO tracks observable used in `computed` by invoking computed function and checking what it reads, try to move `self.showNotAddressalbe()` to variable before first if, so that KO can see that you are getting values from both logisticDestinationFilter and showNotAddressable observables

Comment: So how do I get the actual value without using peek? If I put it inside a var first it does not work unfortunately:  `var showNotAddressable = self.showNotAddressable; if (!showNotAddressable.peek()) {....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use "peek":

```
self.showNotAddressable.peek()
```

This means "just take the current value and do not subsribe to changes".

This prevents "filteredlogisticsDestinations" computed from subscription to changes of the "showNotAddressable" observable.

#### Update 1

To enable subscriptions, you can simply write:

```
self.showNotAddressable()
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. I must have read over this. But how do I get the value of the property without using .peek() then?

Comment: `self.showNotAddressable()` gets the value _and_ creates a subscription to changes of this observable.

Comment: simply self.showNotAddressable(), @Thomas - i've updated the answer.